# SQL Command to find the number of months in a year

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Oracle supports six calendar systems. Following are the different calendars.

- Arabic Hijrah
- English Hijrah
- Gregorian
- Japanese Imperial
- Persian
- ROC Official (Republic of China)
- Thai Buddha

I wanted to know the number of months per a year in every calendar. Is there any sql command to get that information?

Comment: All calendars have 12 months in a year. The length of year and individual months may differ though. Can you be a little more precise your question? i.e: expected output, calculation rules, etc...

Answer (score 1):

SQL - not as far as I know.  My favorite reference for this sort of thing is [Calendrical Calculations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521777526).  There's also [Calendrical Tabulations](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521782538) which provides 300 years (1900-2200) of day-by-day equivalences between many different calendars.  Ed Reingold, one of the authors of the afore-mentioned books, does have a rather nifty little applet which allows you to view the current date in many different calendar systems (which of course begs the question, "Which one is truly the **right** calendar system?") - find it [here](http://emr.cs.iit.edu/home/reingold/calendar-book/Calendrica.html).  You can also buy the software used for the applet [here](http://emr.cs.iit.edu/home/reingold/calendar-book/second-edition/CIIT.html), or can [contact the authors](mailto:reingold@iit.edu?subject=Calendar code use (free software)) if you want to use it in free software.  A collection of Dr. Reingold's papers on calendars and related numerical stuff can be found [here](http://emr.cs.iit.edu/home/reingold/calendar-book/papers/).

Party like it's 1999...